# More trouble with the same proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503730/having-trouble-with-one-step-of-computation) about a proof and now I have two more questions. Here is how I understand the proof (second half):

If $m_T$ has no multiple roots it looks like this: $(T-\lambda_1)...(T-\lambda_k)$. The idea is to show that every generalized eigen vectors also is an eigen vector. To do so pick an eigenvalue $\lambda = \lambda_i$ for some $i$ and let $U $ be the space spanned by the generalized eigen vectors of $\lambda$. Let $v$ be some vector in $U$. The goal is to show $(T-\lambda)v=0$. This can be shown easily by using that $T-\lambda_j = (T-\lambda)+(\lambda-\lambda_j) = N+cI$ from which it is clear that all $T-\lambda_j $ are invertible. Inverting all except $T-\lambda$ results in $(T-\lambda)v=0 $.

> What I don't understand is: where is the assumption used that there
>   are no multiple roots in $m_T$?
>
> And: why is it stated in the solution that the only eigen value of
>   $(T-\lambda_m)|_U$ is $0$? It does not seem to be used in the proof.
>
> And also: where is it used that $V$ is a complex vector space?

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}$You mean $m_{T}$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$, and the $\lambda_{i}$ are distinct.

You may use the result that if $m_{T} = f g$, with $\gcd(f, g) = 1$, then the underlying vector space is the direct sum
$$
V = \ker(f(T)) \oplus \ker(g(T)).
$$
This is because there are polynomials $s, t$ such that
$$
1 = g s + f t,\tag{bezout}
$$
so that
$$
1 = g(T) s(T) + f(T) t(T),
$$
and for $v \in V$ one has
$$
v = g(T) s(T) v + f(T) t(T) v.
$$
Now $$g(T) s(T) v \in \im(g(T)) \subseteq \ker(f(T)),$$ as $f(T) g(T) = m_{T}(T) = 0$. So $v \in \ker(f(T)) + \ker(g(T))$, and (bezout) implies that $\ker(f(T)) \cap \ker(g(T)) = \{ 0 \}$.

Now start applying this to $f = X - \lambda_{1}$, $g = (X - \lambda_{2}) \cdots (X - \lambda_{k})$. Because the $\lambda_{i}$ are distinct, you have $\gcd(f,g) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. And: why is it stated in the solution that the only eigen value of $(T-\lambda_m)|_U$ is $0$?